# Converted app to StoryBoards, pre launch exception in libc++abi.dylib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception

I converted my existing app to +iOS5 with storyboards.

I get an exception before the app reaches applicationDidLaunch..

I've pasted the log right here: http://pastebin.com/9us4K7t5

Any help is greatly appreciated because honestly I'm pretty clueless a.t.m.

Comment: Could you upload somewhere your storyboard file? I'd bet that you're setting some parameter incorrectly.

Comment: It's related to Xcode 5 / iOS 7 SDK - http://osxdev.ru/blog/podcast/141.html
As this is under NDA we cannot further discuss this issue here.